# How to display Image from folder using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, image, entity-framework

I create entity outside my Project
[this is solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4f7r.png)

My entity Post

```
[Table("Post")]
public partial class Post
{
    public int PostID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Picture { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string ViewNumber { get; set; }

    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public int LikeNumber { get; set; }

    public int? CommentID { get; set; }
}
```

My Post Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpPost(Post model, HttpPostedFileBase txtImg)
    {
            var db = new ShareImageDbContext();

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
            if (txtImg != null)
            {
                txtImg.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Images/")
                                                      + txtImg.FileName);
                var post = new Post();
                post.PostID = model.PostID;
                post.Title = model.Title;
                post.Description = model.Description;
                post.CategoryID = model.CategoryID;     
                var userSession = new UserLogin();                    
                userSession = (UserLogin)Session[ShareImage.Common.CommonConstants.USER_SESSION];
                post.UserID = userSession.UserID;                     
                post.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                post.Picture = txtImg.FileName;
                db.Posts.Add(post);
                db.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Homeuser");
                }

                    else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Đăng ảnh thất bại!");
            }
        }
        return View(txtImg);
        }
```

My Post Database
[I inserted some post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tV8o0.png)

I want to display all Post on View. And I call Model as below.

```
@model IEnumerable<Model.EF.Post>
```

and I call foreach

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

but it has an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I can display my image in Images folder as code following, but I want to show more attribute of Post table such as Title, Discription, CreateDate...

```
@foreach(var imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images")))
{
   var img = new FileInfo(imgPath);
   <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Images/{0}", img.Name))" />
   <hr />
}
```

Please guide me how to fix it, Thanks!

Comment: I have a feeling that your `ModelState.IsValid` is returning `false` and your this line  `return View(txtImg);` is being executed. I am not sure what you have in your view. But usually it does not makes sense to return the posted file back to the view ( you have a view model being posted to the action method). If you are being successfully redirected to Index action, you need to make sure that you are setting/initializing any properties which could be `NULL` before using that in the view.

Answer (score 0):

In your view use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` for strings and 
`<img src="<%= ResolveUrl(item.Picture) %>" alt="" />` for images

Problem caused because somewhere you do not set or create object. You have reference that has null value. It raises in view or controller. It will be nice if you provide your error message.